# Linker error involving boost_lock

Tags: c++, boost, linker-errors, archlinux

I'm working on a game engine http://ducttape-dev.org that uses boost as one of the dependencies. One day, as I was writing a test app that linked to my game engine, the Extruder of OgreProcedural threw this type of liker error. After troubleshooting and googling for a couple hours, I did a system update (I'm running archlinux) and rebuilt all the dependencies. Rebooted, still got same kind of error. Tried to rebuild the engine, and got the linker error. Every time I try to link the engine, it throws this error http://pastebin.com/PGH25Yuy.

this just happened to be on libMyGUI, but I gotten it referencing files in the engine instead, and all in the format of "(error stuff) referenced in section (more error stuff) [non virtual thunk to (some file) of (some file) defined in discarded section (some file)". I can build MyGUI from source and get no errors, I can build boost from source and get no errors. I don't know how to troubleshoot this. I don't even know what this means. Any help (even if you could just tell me what kind of error this is) would be *greatly* appreciated.

archlinux x64, amd64 athlon x2, 5Gb RAM, gcc 4.6.2, binutils 2.21.1, boost 1.47.0

Comment: I'm disappointed that "Extruder of OgreProcedural" means that the engine uses Ogre3D, rather than the much more interesting situation of a game which procedurally extrudes ogres. ;-)

Comment: Oh, don't even get me started on the troll matrices. We had to cut them out, at least until we've reached 0.4

Comment: The way to indicate that a problem was solved is to accept the answer, not to edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously I had a similar error after updating to gcc 4.6.2. The weird thing was that downgrading of all packages (gcc, libtool, boost) did not fix the problem. The problem appears to be a mixed compilation: I reupgraded all packages (newest versions of repo) then threw away old compilation data (make clean) and rebuilt the whole thing. Then it worked.

Here the similar error I got:

> .text._ZN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorISt12out_of_rangeEEED2Ev' referenced in section .text._ZN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorISt12out_of_rangeEEED1Ev[boost::exception_detail::clone_impl >::~clone_impl()]' of ./source/gepetto/.libs/libgepetto.a(libslab_la-layout.o): defined in discarded section .text._ZN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorISt12out_of_rangeEEED2Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorISt12out_of_rangeEEED5Ev]' of ./source/gepetto/.libs/libgepetto.a(libslab_la-layout.o)

Comment: Tried reinstalling gcc, binutils, libtool, boost, boost-libs, and ogre and mygui packages, and make clean, but I am still getting the linker error. I'm going to try rebuilding mygui and maybe all the other packages, in case it is a problem with precompiled bins.